# Modifying a list outside a 'While' loop after running it through the 'While' loop

Tags: python, list

I'm currently trying to create my own game of TicTacToe from the ground up and I'm currently having difficulty with a 'while' loop corresponding to a list that I have created.
I'm using the following list:

```
board = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

to mark all 9 slots on a 3x3 game of TicTacToe.
However when player one makes a move(in slot '1' for example) the list should be changed to show

```
board = [X,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

This should continue on until all 9 indexes(I believe is the appropriate term) within the list should be taken up by either 'X' or 'O' which will equal a tie in the game!

For now I'm just experimenting as I go along so pardon the rest of the code but the full code I'm using is:

```
board = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
def CreateBoard(board):
    print('   |   |')
    print(' ' + board[7] + ' | ' + board[8] + ' | ' + board[9])
    print('   |   |')
    print('-----------')
    print('   |   |')
    print(' ' + board[4] + ' | ' + board[5] + ' | ' + board[6])
    print('   |   |')
    print('-----------')
    print('   |   |')
    print(' ' + board[1] + ' | ' + board[2] + ' | ' + board[3])
    print('   |   |')

PlayerOne = 'X'
Turn = 'player one'
GameRunning = True



while [0] == 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 or 6 or 7 or 8 or 9 in board == True:
    if Turn == 'player one':
       letter = 'X'
       Move = input("Please pick where to go next: ")
       Move = int(Move)
       if Move in board:
          board.insert(Move, letter)
          board.remove(Move)
          print(board)
          Turn = 'player two'




       else:
          print("This move is invalid")

  if Turn == 'player two':
     letter = 'O'
     Move = input("Pick where to go next: ")
     Move = int(Move)
     if Move in board:
        board.insert(Move, letter)
        board.remove(Move)
        print(board)
        Turn = 'player one'


     else:
         print("This move is invalid")
```

The output I get as I go along are:
[image]

I'm guessing the while loop is running the list that's outside of the loop but I'm trying to find a way to change that!
I've also not yet worked out why its printing 'That move is invalid'!

Comment: What statement are you trying to make with this loop?

Comment: Your while condition is going to be always true. your condition is botched. because of that, your "if" check hits the "else" block.

Comment: Statement? not quite sure what you mean but I'm trying to get the list at the beginning of the code to be changed to whatever values end up replacing everything in the list after it runs through the 'While' loop

Comment: I see where I went wrong with the if statement in the 'while' loop and I've just fixed that

Comment: Less familiar with python, but if you made it a string instead of an array and used regexes, wouldn't that simplify your test? You could still edit the indexed characters and treat it like an array, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with your while loop is that non-zero integers are always considered to be "true".  Therefore

```
while [0] == 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 or 6 or 7 or 8 or 9 in board == True:
```

actually means "while the list containing 0 is equal to the integer 1 (always false), or 2 (true), or 3 (true)... or 9 in (board) (true if 9 is still on the board), then enter the block."

I believe that you meant was more:

```
while any((cell in range(1,10) for cell in board)):
```

which means while any cell in the board is in the range from 1 (inclusive) to 10 (exclusive), then enter the block.

Take a look at this code:

```
player = [
    {"name": "Player One", "letter": "X"},
    {"name": "Player Two", "letter": "O"},
]


def print_board(board):
    def print_vbars():
        print("   |   |")
    def print_hbars():
        print("-----------")

    print_vbars()
    for row in range(3):
        print(" {} | {} | {}".format(*(board[row*3 : row*3+3])))
        print_vbars()
        print_hbars()
        print_vbars()
    print_vbars()


def final_state(board):
    winning_combinations = (
        (0,1,2), # Horizontal top row
        (3,4,5), # Horizontal middle row
        (6,7,8), # Horizontal bottom row
        (0,3,6), # Vertical left row
        (1,4,2), # Vertical middle row
        (2,5,7), # Vertical right row
        (0,4,8), # Downward diagonal
        (2,4,6), # Upward diagonal
    )
    for letter in ("X", "O"):
        for combination in winning_combinations:
            row_state = (board[index] for index in combination)
            if all(map(lambda cell: letter == cell, row_state)):
                return "{} wins".format(letter)

    if all(map(lambda cell: cell in ("X", "O"), board)):
        return "Game is a draw."

    return False


def play_game():
    board = list(range(9))
    starting_player = 0
    turn = 0
    active_player = starting_player
    while final_state(board) is False:
        turn += 1
        print("Turn {}:".format(turn))
        print_board(board)
        name, letter = player[active_player]["name"], player[active_player]["letter"]
        move = None
        while move is None:
            try:
                move = input("{} please make your move: ".format(name))
                move = int(move)
                if move in board:
                    board[move] = letter
                    print("{} played {} on {}.".format(name, letter, move))
                    active_player = 1 - active_player
                else:
                    print("Move {} is invalid.".format(move))
                    move = None
            except Exception as e:
                    print("Move {} is invalid.".format(move))
                    move = None
    print_board(board)
    print(final_state(board))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    play_game()
```

Comment: In essence I suppose I could call it homework and while your code would solve the problem, the reason I'm doing the code through experimenting through what i'm familiar with is to compound what I already know to make sure I do fully understand it and a lot of the features in your code don't serve my own reason for writing the code but other than that your code would fix a lot of the issues

Comment: I updated my answer to more directly address your question.